# Can underlying parquet files be deleted without negatively impacting DeltaLake _delta_log

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

Using `.vacuum()` on a DeltaLake table is very slow (see [Delta Lake (OSS) Table on EMR and S3 - Vacuum takes a long time with no jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62822265/5060792)).

If I manually deleted the underlying parquet files and did not add a new `json` log file or add a new `.checkpoint.parquet` file and change the `_delta_log/_last_checkpoint` file that points to it; what would the negative impacts to the DeltaLake table be, if any?

Obviously time-traveling, i.e. loading a previous version of the table that relied on the parquet files I removed, would not work.  What I want to know is, would there be any issues reading, writing, or appending to the current version of the DeltaLake table?

What I am thinking of doing in pySpark:

```py
### Assuming a working SparkSession as `spark`

from subprocess import check_output
import json
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

awscmd = "aws s3 cp s3://my_s3_bucket/delta/_delta_log/_last_checkpoint -"
last_checkpoint = str(json.loads(check_output(awscmd, shell=True).decode("utf-8")).get('version')).zfill(20)

s3_bucket_path = "s3a://my_s3_bucket/delta/"

df_chkpt_del = (
    spark.read.format("parquet")
    .load(f"{s3_bucket_path}/_delta_log/{last_checkpoint}.checkpoint.parquet")
    .where(F.col("remove").isNotNull())
    .select("remove.*")
    .withColumn("deletionTimestamp", F.from_unixtime(F.col("deletionTimestamp")/1000))
    .withColumn("delDateDiffDays", F.datediff(F.col("deletionTimestamp"), F.current_timestamp()))
    .where(F.col("delDateDiffDays") < -7 )
)
```

There are a lot of options from here.  One could be:

```py
df_chkpt_del.select("path").toPandas().to_csv("files_to_delete.csv", index=False)
```

Where I could read `files_to_delete.csv` into a bash array and then use a simple bash `for` loop passing each parquet file s3 path to an `aws s3 rm` command to remove the files one by one.

This may be slower than `vacuum()`, but at least it will not be consuming cluster resources while it is working.

If I do this, will I also have to either:

1. write a new `_delta_log/000000000000000#####.json` file that correctly documents these changes?
2. write a new `000000000000000#####.checkpoint.parquet` file that correctly documents these changes and change the `_delta_log/_last_checkpoint` file to point to that `checkpoint.parquet` file?

The second option would be easier.

However, if there will be no negative effects if I just remove the files and don't change anything in the `_delta_log`, then that would be the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR. Answering this question.

> If I manually deleted the underlying parquet files and did not add a new json log file or add a new .checkpoint.parquet file and change the _delta_log/_last_checkpoint file that points to it; what would the negative impacts to the DeltaLake table be, if any?

**Yes**, this could potentially corrupt your delta table.

Let me briefly answers how delta-lake reads a version using `_delta_log`.

If you want to read version `x` then it will go to delta log of all versions from `1` to `x-1` and will make a running sum of parquet files to read. Summary of this process is saved as a `.checkpoint` after every 10th version to make this process of running sum efficient.

#### What do I mean by this running sum?

Assume, 
version 1 log says, add `add file_1, file_2, file_3`
version 2 log says, add `delete file_1, file_2, and add file_4`

So when reading version no 2, total instruction will be
`add file_1, file_2, file_3 -> delete file_1, file_2, and add file_4`

So, resultant files read will be file_3 and file_4.

#### What if you delete a parquet from a file system?

Say in version 3, you delete `file_4` from file system. If you don't use `.vacuum` then delta log will not know that `file_4` is not present, it will try to read it and will fail.

Comment: Look at the `df_chkpt_del` I made, it keeps only the files that have been flagged as `removed` from the DeltaLake tables more than 7 days ago (I can set this to whatever time period I choose).  So in your example, if `file_1` and `file_2` were removed more than seven days ago, then those are the only files  I would be removing.  I would not ever remove `file_4` because it has not been flagged in the `_delta_log`s as having been removed at all, not even 1 day ago.